# Is there any hadith about having pet cats?

Tags: reference-request, cats

Asalam o alaikum. I would like to know if there is any Hadith about having pet cat in house . I've heard somewhere that there is a Hadith about it

Comment: I am not really aware of any hadith about having pet cats. There are ahadith about feral cats who wander around people homes and that cats are pure, and ahadith that harming them is bad. Such as: https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:92 , and https://sunnah.com/bukhari:745 , https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:369 etc.

Comment: you will find many in https://sunnah.com/search?q=cat